# Page not found on magento admin after clearing the cache

Tags: magento, caching, http-status-code-404, admin

I am working on magento CE to develop online store. I updated something in the file. Then to view the changes I had to clear the cache  (magento/var/cache), but after clearing the cache I got the following error on both the admin panel and the front store. 
    404 error: Page not found.

I have tried few solutions but nothing is working. I am unable to find out what went wrong. I have deleted the cache a lot of time before, but this never happened. When I restore the cache files from bin, everything start working fine. but I can not view any of my changes without cache refresh. I have revert all the changes but clearing cache leads to the same error.

Cache folder have complete permissions(write,modify). Also I have checked the related tables like customer_group, core_website, core_store_group,core_store in DB, All have the right values in the columns.

Is there any way to read the exceptions in magento causing this error?

Comment: Go to admin panel `Configuration > Developer > Log Settings > Enabled > Yes`
Then refresh the page and check var/log folder for exceptions and system errors

Comment: Thanks Ahmed, I can see the exceptions now.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, there was an unexpected folder created with name .xml which was creating error. I deleted th folder and the error is gone.